# Routing to custom action in controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add ajax that would render a partial upon clicking a div.

This the link:

```
<h1 id="comments_viewall"><%= link_to "View All", videos_update_comments_path, remote: true%></h1>
```

I have the custom method in the videos controller:

```
def update_comments
    puts "hello"
end
```

And the routes are as such:

```
get 'videos/update_comments'
```

However, I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:3000/videos/update_comments 404 (Not Found) 

Started GET "/videos/update_comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-05 13:49:02 -0400
Processing by VideosController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"update_comments"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 in show
  Video Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "videos".* FROM "videos" WHERE "videos"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "update_comments"]]
 Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Video with id=update_comments):
  app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:94:in `show'
```

I followed what  bunch of stack overflow questions told me to do, but its still not working..

Comment: Post your `show` method and `rake routes` output.

Comment: @vicli Did my answer resolve your issue? Let me know the results and query, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `get 'videos/update_comments'` above the `show` route defined for `videos` resource.

For example:

```
get 'videos/update_comments'
resources :videos
```

As currently, when you do a GET request for `videos/update_comments`, Rails finds the first match from routes.rb and routes the request there. So, it matches `videos/:id` route and routes the request to `VideosController#show` action instead of `VideosController#update_comments`.

You can see it clearly in the generated log

```
Started GET "/videos/update_comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-05 13:49:02 -0400
Processing by VideosController#show as JS
```

By moving the `update_comments` route before `show` route, whenever a GET request for `videos/update_comments` is made, the first match would be `get 'videos/update_comments'` in your routes and the request would be directed to `VideosController#update_comments`

**UPDATE**

You could also define the `update_comments` route within a `collection` as suggested by *@Addicted* in the comments provided that you have defined the routes using `resources :videos`

```
  resources :videos do
    collection do
      get 'update_comments'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Since Videos Controller exists and corresponding routes also seems to be there, then why not add update_comments under collection.

Comment: That's a good option. I just gave a general example as OP hasn't shared how actually the routes are defined.